# Python - Vectorized operation to filter http response json

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

I have a list that basically comprises certain keys of data object received in HTTP response (json)

let the list be something like

```
 ['uid', 'status', 'profile.name', 'profile.login', 'profile.mobile']
```

I am parsing a nested json something like-

```
{
    "uid":"a1234",
    "status":active,
    "native":false,
    "profile":{
                 "name": "xyz",
                 "alias": "z",
                 "login": "abc",
              }

}
```

using pandas.json_normalise() on the above json will give me a dataframe like

```
        uid     status     native     profile.name     profile.alias     profile.login
    
   0    a1234   active     false      xyz              z                 abc
```

Now how do I use the above list and create a new list or dataframe (either is ok) to keep values from response according to the first list while handling any values not present in the http response json as NA or "".
Expecting to get a list or dataframe like -

```
['a1234', 'active', 'xyz', 'abc', '']
```

or

```
        uid     status     profile.name     profile.login    profile.mobile
    
   0    a1234   active     xyz              abc              ""
```

currently I am looping over first list to achieve this but it is slower, any way I could use vectorized operations to speed this process up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `reindex` like this

```
print(pd.json_normalize(js) # js is my json
        .reindex(columns=['uid', 'status', 'profile.name', 
                          'profile.login', 'profile.mobile'])
        .fillna(''))
#      uid  status profile.name profile.login profile.mobile
# 0  a1234  active          xyz           abc
```

Comment: Thanks, this does solve my problem and is faster than using for loop, however do you know if I can improve the efficiency or is reindex() extremely efficient?

Comment: @ABD the question is do you have several rows in your json or just one? if only one at a time, then going with the library `json` would be more efficient than pandas

Comment: my thing is as I am working with a large number of input values (above 100K) for which HTTPS calls need to be made (sometimes more than one) and the results of each call(s) for the users need to be stored, so each time there will be a single row which I am then concatenating to a pandas data frame to hold either 50-100 such results and write them all to a file together. I am using such batches just so that write to file doesn't slow down operations as I am using multithreading to reduce time required to process input